# Verificar a quantidade de elementos dentro de uma div com um id dentro de uma classe em javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou querendo acessar uma `id` dentro de uma classe css para verificar a quantidade de parágrafos existentes dentro da mesma. Em javascript como eu poderia faze-lo nesse caso?

Exemplo:

```
<div class="classe">
    <div id="algo">
       <p>paragrafo1</p>
       <p>paragrafo2</p>
       <p>paragrafo3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: testa `alert(document.querySelectorAll('#algo p').length);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar o `document.querySelectorAll` para selecionar vários elementos com um seletor CSS.

No teu caso poderia ser assim:

```js
var qtd = document.querySelectorAll('#algo p').length;
console.log('A quantidade de <p>\'s é', qtd);
```

```html
<div class="classe">
    <div id="algo">
       <p>paragrafo1</p>
       <p>paragrafo2</p>
       <p>paragrafo3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```